Неполная основа или однородный ряд?

Наши дети пойдут на концерт и если им там понравится, то останутся до
утра.

Меня интересует последняя часть предложения: "дети пойдут и останутся" будут однородные членами или все же это разные основы ССП, которые разделены подчинительным союзом (СПП)? Формально подлежащего "они" здесь нет, но смущает "то".

Поставьте запятую или тире перед «и» - и всё встанет на место: вторая часть (после «и») - сложноподчинённое предложение с «то» в главной части и «если» - в придаточной.
